# Sequelize. How to use different value of parameters in creation

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, database, sequelize.js

I'm trying write create user function. I have such code

```
   createUser: function (user) {
        return db.User.create({
            id: user.id,
            username: user.username,
            password: sha1(user.password),
            first_name: user.first_name,
            last_name: user.last_name,
            email: user.email,
            allow_password: user.allow_password
        });
    }
```

but it's correct only when I fill all user's fields. Actually, I strongly need only username and email, but when I put only 2 parameters - I've gotten 500 server error. How I can do other rows implicit?

Comment: I think I can check every row like this `if (!user.last_name) {        user.last_name = null; } ` but it's not a good choice I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: you have to convert password before the query

```
createUser: function (user) {
        if(user.password) {
          user.password = sha1(user.password);
        }
        return db.User.create({
            id: user.id,
            username: user.username,
            password: user.password,
            first_name: user.first_name,
            last_name: user.last_name,
            email: user.email,
            allow_password: user.allow_password
        });
    }
```